# Multiple pandas dataframes to HTML

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a project that I'm working on where the end result are grouped and aggregated dataframes that are going to be viewed. I currently have it so that each table outputs as an HTML file using `df.to_html()` What would be the best way to have multiple pandas dataframes (with different column names) output into one HTML file? Would producing several HTML files, then combining be the best solution?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question, I used the following. It may not be the most elegant solution (formatting or otherwise):

```
html1 = yourdataframe1.to_html()
html2 = yourdataframe2.to_html()
x = [html1, html2]
mail.HTMLBody = x[0]+x[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best solution is to [concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) dataframe first with `pandas` and export the result with `df.to_html()`.
Merging HTML pages is not that easy, since HTML code embeds layout information.